# Graph minus a point has at most 2 connected components

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, np-complete

Let $G(V,E)$ be a connected undirected graph (undirected=easier), such that, $S_x=V\setminus\{x\}, \forall x \in V$ is a subset of vertices of G. Then the induced subgraph $G[S_x]$ is the graph whose vertex set is $S_x$ and whose edges set consists of all of the edges in $E$ that have both endpoints in $S_x$.

Prove that a graph $G(V,E)$ has a Hamiltonian path (not necesarily a cycle) if the induced subgraphs $\forall x \in V, G[S_x]$ have at most 2 connected components.

Comment: What is your thinking

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^ What have you tried? Do you have any ideas? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better

Comment: You need to add your own efforts to solve the question and where you are stuck. Or your question might get downvoted and closed.

Comment: My thoughs. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3963112/set-minus-a-point-has-at-most-2-connected-components

Comment: I am stuck in finding a proof.

Comment: One side of the implication it's obvious, if you have a point $x \in E$ and $\{A,B,C \subset V$ \ $ \{x\}\}$ such that A, B, C are disjoint then there can't be a Hamiltonian path that goes through $a_1 \in A$, $b_1 \in B$ and $c_1 \in C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is probably the *simplest* counterexample.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering!